# Can't replace text on string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have string like:

```
          Student 12:00AMLeoPan        Final points        
<!--<div class='icon displayOn' ><span onclick=';' title=''></span></div>-->0.5
      &nbsp;         2.00<!--<div class='icon'><spanonclick='' title=''></span></div>-->
```

I want to replace string StartWith `<!--<div` to end `</div>-->`, and string `&nbsp` to `""` values.

I tried with my code:

```
string finalResult = Regex.Replace(abc, "<!--<div" + ".*</div>-->&nbsp;", "")
                          .Replace("<!--<div" + ".*</div>-->", "")
                          .Replace("&nbsp;", "");`
```

But `Regex.Replace` can't replace.

How to remove this string? Thanks.

Updated 1:

Thanks, @Mark.

I tried with: `.Replace("<!--<div" + ".*</div>-->", "")`.

And it remove all:

`<!--<div class='icon displayOn' ><span onclick=';' title=''></span></div>-->0.5
      &nbsp;         2.00<!--<div class='icon'><spanonclick='' title=''></span></div>-->`.

Result only: `Student 12:00AMLeoPan        Final points`.

You can see I have two have start with: `<!--<div` and end with: `</div>-->`.

But it replaces all. And want final result to show like:

`Student 12:00AMLeoPan        Final points     0.5      &nbsp;         2.00`

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thanks, @Rob. Have you any method to resolve my problem?

Comment: try using the string replace method.

Comment: Also beware that doing .* on html tags will do a greedy match and find the outer most tags that match the pattern.  Use .*? to do a non greedy match.

Comment: Thanks @WhoIsRich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Regex.Replace` returns a `string`, so your 2nd and 3rd `Replace` calls are actually calling `String.Replace`, which doesn't support regex. Don't chain the calls - call Regex.Replace explicitly each time, e.g.

```
string r1 = Regex.Replace(abc, "<!--<div.*?</div>-->&nbsp;", "");
string r2 = Regex.Replace(r1, "<!--<div.*?</div>-->", "");
string finalResult = Regex.Replace(r2, "&nbsp;", "");
```

Update: As mentioned by @WhoIsRich in a comment on the question, the regex was modified to be non-greedy.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. I read a comment from #WholsRich. And your answer resolves my question.